# Joomla Form Maker where to find html form template

Tags: html, joomla

I'm working on Joomla project which is using [`Form Maker`](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/22319). My task is to improve `HTML template` but I absolutely can't find it. I've searched everywhere I could in the extension's directory folder.

Structure:

```
|-models 
|----formaker.php
|----index.html
|-uploads
|----index.html
|-views
|----formmaker
|--------tmpl
|------------default.php
|------------default.xml
|------------index.html
|------------main.js
|--------index.html
|--------view.html.php
|----index.html
|-controller.php
|-formmaker.php
|-index.html
|-wd_captcha.php
```

From my point of view main file is in `views/formmaker/tmpl/default.php` but I've didn't find the way how I can modify especially the HTML template to change the form params.

Update - Structure of default.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="Form">
        <message></message>
    </layout>
    <fields name="request">
        <fieldset name="request" addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_formmaker/models/forms"    >
            <field name="id" type="modal_contacts" label="Select a Form" required="true"/>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</metadata>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `Form Maker` extension the only possible solution to change the HTML markup of the form elements, it's only to rewriting the whole script for your needs.

Wouldn't recommend to use this script, even Premium version.

Answer (score -1):

Form parametars are in xml file. Try at this path `views/formmaker/formmaker.xml`

Comment: Where did you found `formmaker.xml` of it's simply even don't exist in the directory

Comment: I meant `default.xml`

Comment: Updated the question, added `default.xml`